# OpenCV output Using Mat object in Jpanel

Tags: java, swing, opencv, image-processing

I know we can output an Image using Jpanel using the following code:

```
   JFrame frame = new JFrame("IMG");
   frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

   frame.setResizable(true);
   frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

   ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(".../img.jpg");
   frame.setSize(image.getIconWidth()+10,image.getIconHeight()+35);

   JLabel label1 = new JLabel(" ", image, JLabel.CENTER);
   frame.getContentPane().add(label1);

   frame.validate();
   frame.setVisible(true);
```

This code would assume that I have created or already have an image file in my directory. But what I want to do is output the image in the Jpanel directly without creating the image file. How do I do that using OpenCV Mat object in JAVA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert `Mat` object to `BufferedImage` object using following method:

```
public static BufferedImage createAwtImage(Mat mat) {

    int type = 0;
    if (mat.channels() == 1) {
        type = BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY;
    } else if (mat.channels() == 3) {
        type = BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR;
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(mat.width(), mat.height(), type);
    WritableRaster raster = image.getRaster();
    DataBufferByte dataBuffer = (DataBufferByte) raster.getDataBuffer();
    byte[] data = dataBuffer.getData();
    mat.get(0, 0, data);

    return image;
}
```

Then you can simply display image using `ImageIcon`:

```
// Load image using Highgui or create Mat object other way you want
Mat mat = Highgui.imread(".../img.jpg");

ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(createAwtImage(mat));
```

Comment: This method doesn't even compile as the return null will always be called

Comment: Please elaborate, what returning null has in common with compiling?

Comment: Check your brackets....return null will always be called. Therefor it will not compile. easy

Comment: Oh, I got it - else statement has been cut out. I have fixed the code, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The idea seems still sound but does not compile (anymore?) with

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
            <artifactId>javacv-platform</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.8</version>
        </dependency>
```

> The method width() is undefined for the type Mat

> The method height() is undefined for the type Mat

> The method get(int, int, byte[]) is undefined for the type Mat

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This fixed version of the above works on bytedeco 1.5.8:

```
    public static BufferedImage createImage(Mat mat) {
        int type = 0;
        if (mat.channels() == 1) {
            type = BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY;
        } else if (mat.channels() == 3) {
            type = BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR;
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(mat.cols(), mat.rows(), type);
        WritableRaster raster = image.getRaster();
        DataBufferByte dataBuffer = (DataBufferByte) raster.getDataBuffer();
        byte[] data = dataBuffer.getData();
        mat.data().get(data);

        return image;
    }
```

Comment: Less detailed version of [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22313258/21144042).