# Problems with portraying OpenCV images on Jpanel

Tags: java, swing, opencv

I'm trying to display an image that has been captured from a VideoCapture object given by the openCV library. I made a small GUI that has a jpanel component which I would like to portray the image on. The images are captured as Mat objects which had to be converted to BufferedImages to be shown on the GUI.

I had done this in a previous working project. Then, I just copied most of the code from there. The problem is that the image that gets drawn on the current project is a mess. I've no good way to explain how it looks like so I will just post an printed screen here:

[image: broken image]

RemoteCam is the variable name of the jpanel. setRemoteCamImage is called from an external Thread which reads from the videoCapture object.

Code:

```
public void setRemoteCamImage(Mat aMat){
    BufferedImage aImg = matToImg(aMat);
    if (!(aImg == null)) {
        Graphics g = RemoteCam.getGraphics();
        g.drawImage(aImg, 0, 0, RemoteCam.getWidth(), RemoteCam.getHeight(), 0, 0, aImg.getWidth(), aImg.getHeight(), null);
    }
}

public static BufferedImage matToImg(Mat in) {
    BufferedImage out;
    byte[] data = new byte[in.height() * in.width() * (int) in.elemSize()];
    int type;
    in.get(0, 0, data);

    if (in.channels() == 0) {
        type = BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY;
    } else {
        type = BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR;

        // Arange the colors from BGR to RGB
        byte b;
        for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i = i + 3){
            b = data[i];
            data[i] = data[i + 2];
            data[i + 2] = b;
        }
    }
    out = new BufferedImage(in.height(), in.width(), type);
    out.getRaster().setDataElements(0, 0, in.height(), in.width(), data);
    return out;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any replies.

Comment: check out this page Graphics.html - how many drawImages do you see???

Comment: what are you trying to say...

Comment: anyway what I'm trying to say is why dont you try the simple method g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, imagewidth, imageheight, null) - I dont even know what the image is supposed to look like

Comment: I've tried that aswell, but there was no change in results. The image shown there is just a normal webcam image, aka a picture of my room, or its supposed to be.

Comment: why dont you try some of these answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27086120/convert-opencv-mat-object-to-bufferedimage?rq=1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22284823/opencv-output-using-mat-object-in-jpanel?rq=1 I dont know Mat - also put the drawImage part inside JPanels paintComponent